# Issue using Stanford CoreNLP parsing models

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

I cannot find the Stanford parsing models for German and French: there is no "germanPCFG.ser.gz" or "frenchFactored.ser.gz" in the jar (stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar) - only english. Have searched through posttagger jar too.

Same issue encountered at : [How to use Stanford CoreNLP with a Non-English parse model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531208/how-to-use-stanford-corenlp-with-a-non-english-parse-model)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again, if it already exists, we only need one copy of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can find them in the download for [the Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/lex-parser.shtml). Look in the models.jar file.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I had the corenlp and the pos tagger downloads, didnt realise I was still missing the parser..  I am however, getting an error when running with the above, possibly due to discrepancy. Have downloaded all the latest versions, but still getting Unknown option: -retainTmpSubcategories: Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz ... done [4.6 sec].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option: -retainTmpSubcategories
 at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options.setOption(Options.java:175)

Comment: You need to add the flag `-parse.flags ""`. (It's sort of a misfeature/bug that we turn this option on by default, because it is useful for English, but it isn't defined for other languages.)

Comment: Many thanks again! Should have added my thanks earlier, but was caught up progressing my code once past that hurdle. Is this in the documentation, and I am not looking in right place..

Answer (score 2):

With [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) you can use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier>         <!-- English models -->
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <classifier>models-german</classifier>  <!-- German models -->
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <classifier>models-spanish</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <classifier>models-chinese</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Maven will download the jar file for the german models to your home directory:
`~/.m2/repository/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.5.2/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models-german.jar`